# Beautifulsoup not able to extract src tag

Tags: beautifulsoup

I want to automate downloading images from imgflip.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url="https://imgflip.com/memegenerator/Drake-Hotline-Bling"
page=requests.get(url)
parsed=bs(page.content,'html.parser')
res=parsed.find_all('img',class_="mm-img shadow")
print(res)
```

When I inspect the page, I see the src tag for the image but the response I get does not have the src tag. I have also tried setting src=True, but it also doesn't work. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On the other hand, with a dynamic website the server might not send
> back any HTML at all. Instead, you’ll receive JavaScript code as a
> response. This will look completely different from what you saw when
> you inspected the page with your browser’s developer tools.

Src: real python.

In my case also, the website sent back javascript code. The solution is to use requests-html or selenium